# Reshaping a Dataframe in pandas(With Date)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and i am looking to mould it into the way i need.
Here is an exact replica of the dataframe i am working on...

```
stack_overflow = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a2','a3','a3','a3'],
                              'value': [10,20,0,33,64,21,87,55,4],
                               'schedule': [22,11,44,55,7,5,3,2,4],
                               'Date':['2020-09-13','2020-09-13','2020-09-13','2020-09-14','2020-09-14','2020-09-14',
                                       '2020-09-15','2020-09-15','2020-09-15']})
```

I am looking to get it into this format

```
          2020-09-13     2020-09-14     2020-09-15    
     Schedule Value  Schedule Value  Schedule Value 
a1      22      10      55      33       3       87
a2      11      20       7      64       2       55
a3      44       0       5      21       4        4
```

I am not a data person, so this is how far i got to.

```
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(stack_overflow,values = ['schedule','value'],index = ['id'],columns = ['Date'])
```

As you can see the output is not very readable at all.
Any suggestions to get the output into the above mentioned format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
pivot_table = (pd.pivot_table(stack_overflow,values = ['schedule','value'],
                             index = ['id'],
                             columns = ['Date'])
                 .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
                 .sort_index(axis=1))
print (pivot_table)
Date 2020-09-13       2020-09-14            2020-09-15           
       schedule value   schedule      value   schedule      value
id                                                               
a1    25.666667  10.0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
a2          NaN   NaN  22.333333  39.333333        NaN        NaN
a3          NaN   NaN        NaN        NaN        3.0  48.666667
```

Comment: Thank you,
This worked. I just had a quick question though.
When i view the data frame in the variable explorer the format is different but when i export it to csv, the format is as i want it to be. Why is that? @jezrael

Comment: @TheStoryTeller - Because MultiIndex not display repeated values, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) - `We’ve “sparsified” the higher levels of the indexes to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes. Note that how the index is displayed can be controlled using the multi_sparse option in pandas.set_options():`